# Find all functions $f(z)$ that are analytic everywhere in the entire complex plane that satisfy $f(2-i)=4i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

This question is apparently related to Cauchy's Integral Formula and related theorems, but I honestly don't know how to start, other than potentially saying that $f(z)$ is every function such that "insert Gauss' Mean Value Theorem here"

Comment: Are you sure there is no additional constraint?

Comment: That is the only constraint.

Comment: Ooo-kay. Can you find all entire functions with $f(0) =  0$?

Comment: I suppose we have $z^n$ where $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$. Further, we have $e^{i0} - 1$. I can't go on like this forever. I'm not sure how to possibly generalize this.

Comment: What could you say about $g(z) = \dfrac{f(z)}{z}$?

Comment: That can't possibly work, because at $0$ it is undefined.

Comment: Have you heard of removable singularities?

Comment: You mean if $f(z)$ is of the form $z*h(z)$, then we get the denominator to cancel out.

Comment: Amounts to that. If $f(0) = 0$, then $g$ defined as above has a removable singularity in $0$, hence without loss of generality is an entire function, and we have $f(z) = z\cdot g(z)$. Conversely, if $h$ is an entire function, then $z\cdot h(z)$ is an entire function with a zero in $0$. Can you translate that to your situation?

Comment: If $f(2-i) = 4i$, then $g$ is defined as having a removable singularity at $2-i$, such that $f(z) = (z-(2-i))g(z)$ and $f(2-i) = 4i$. Conversely, if $h$ is an entire function, then $(z-(2-i))h(z)$ is an entire function with a $4i$ in $2-i$? So, from this analysis $f(z)$ is every function $(z-(2-i))h(z)$?

Comment: Not quite. $(z - (2-i))\cdot g(z)$ has a zero at $2-i$.

Comment: If $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z-(2-i)}$ though, isn't that removable?

Comment: But you have $f(2-i) = 4i \neq 0$, so that gives you a pole.

Comment: Yes, but we then have $(4i * ((2-i) - (2-i)))/((2-i)-(2-i))$, and those cancel out. I don't think I follow completely.

Comment: I still am not completely sure about this question.

Comment: Although, this question has been posted for a while, I was, coincidentally, presented with the exact same problem, as an exercise to study for an exam, with the $additional$ condition that for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $\big|f(z)\big|<e^{2}$ (i.e., $f$ is bounded everywhere over the complex plane); I added this comment in the event that the OP left this condition out, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is an entire function with $f(z_0) = w_0$ for some (arbitrary) $z_0,\, w_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, then $g = f - w_0$ is an entire function with $g(z_0) = 0$. And that means that there is an entire function $h$ with $g(z) = (z - z_0)\cdot h(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. So we have $f(z) = (z-z_0)\cdot h(z) + w_0$.

Conversely, if $h$ is an arbitrary entire function, then $f$ defined by $f(z) = (z-z_0)\cdot h(z) + w_0$ is an entire function with $f(z_0) = w_0$.

Now specialise to the given $z_0$ and $w_0$.

Comment: You get $g(z) = (z-z_0)h(z)$ from the fact that $g(z_0) = (z_0 - z_0)h(z_0) = 0$, correct?

Comment: From $g(z_0) = f(z_0) - w_0 = 0$, we conclude the existence of an entire $h$ with $g(z) = (z-z_0)\cdot h(z)$. For example by observing that $\dfrac{g(z)}{z-z_0}$ has a removable singularity in $0$, or by looking at the power series expansion of $g$ with centre $z_0$.